# Detect URL redirection + ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, redirect, asp.net-core-1.1

I'm trying to redirect webform urls to .net core.
Lets say user entered **www.test.com/index.aspx** in URL, it will redirect to **www.test.com/home/index**

So in the HomeController, IActionResult Index method, how can I detect that it was redirected from index.aspx to home/index?

My research shows that it would be something like below, but they are not compatible with .net core

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = "HEAD";
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

    string location;
    using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        location = response.GetResponseHeader("Location");
    }
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not compatible with .Net Core 1.1, however is compatible with .Net Core 2.0. So if possible just change target framework.

You should also adjust your code slightly. In .Net Core `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()` method will throw `WebException` if redirect happens. So you should try-catch it and analyze `WebException.Response`:

```
try
{
    using (request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
    }
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    var location = e.Response.Headers["Location"];
}
```

However I suggest using `HttpClient` as alternative. It will allow you to do the job without exception handling:

```
using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
    handler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
    using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, uri))
    using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request))
    {
        var location = response.Headers.Location;
    }
}
```

`HttpClient` approach works both for .Net Core 1.1 and 2.0 versions.

**UPDATE**

There is no something similar to `IsRedirected` property in `HttpResponseMessage` but you could use simple extension method for it:

```
public static class HttpResponseMessageExtensions
{
    public static bool IsRedirected(this HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        var code = response.StatusCode;
        return code == HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently || code == HttpStatusCode.Found;
    }
}

bool redirected = response.WasRedirected();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm trying with it, but is there any boolean that detects redirection? For example, IsRedirected = true